# Is there a way to do this in one line?

Tags: java, arrays

I feel like this two line program should be expressible in one line but I can't get the `{}` array literal to work inside the `asList` call. Is there a way?

```
String[] a = {"Whiskey", "Tango", "Foxtrot"};
myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Comment: Why is this such an issue for you?

Comment: Because I care about writing beautiful code. And in the answer below I learned something very useful!

Comment: I don't think this makes it any more readable especially if you have more than a few items, but sure thing enjoy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) receives an ellipsis (`T...`), so you just don't need the array literal:

```
myList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Whiskey", "Tango", "Foxtrot"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`myList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Whiskey", "Tango", "Foxtrot"));`

Answer (score 0):

As I don't think you need string array here, you can use like that

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("Whiskey");add("Tango")add("Foxtrot");}};
```